Error creating symbolic links during Electron build
Trying to build my Electron app using Electron Builder fails with an error related to symbolic links:
Scanning the drive for archives:
    1 file, 5635384 bytes (5504 KiB)

    Extracting archive: C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\electron-builder\Cache\winCodeSign\496893375.7z
    --
    Path = C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\electron-builder\Cache\winCodeSign\496893375.7z
    Type = 7z
    Physical Size = 5635384
    Headers Size = 1492
    Method = LZMA2:24m LZMA:20 BCJ2
    Solid = +
    Blocks = 2

    Sub items Errors: 2

    Archives with Errors: 1

    Sub items Errors: 2

    errorOut=ERROR: Cannot create symbolic link : A required privilege is not held by the client. : C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\electron-builder\Cache\winCodeSign\496893375\darwin\10.12\lib\libcrypto.dylib
    ERROR: Cannot create symbolic link : A required privilege is not held by the client. : C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\electron-builder\Cache\winCodeSign\496893375\darwin\10.12\lib\libssl.dylib

    command='C:\techstone\electronjs\parts-app\node_modules\7zip-bin\win\x64\7za.exe' x -bd 'C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\electron-builder\Cache\winCodeSign\496893375.7z' '-oC:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\electron-builder\Cache\winCodeSign\496893375'
    workingDir=C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\electron-builder\Cache\winCodeSign
  • Above command failed, retrying 0 more times

Project Information:

Electron: ^31.3.0
Electron-builder: ^24.13.3
OS: Windows 10 (also testing on Windows 11)
Node.js version: 16.x

package.json:
{
  "name": "parts-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "main/electron.js",
  "homepage": ".",
  "dependencies": { ... },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run start-react\" \"npm run start-electron\"",
    "build": "react-scripts build && electron-builder",
    "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps",
  },
  "build": {
    "appId": "com.parts-app",
    "directories": {
      "output": "dist"
    },
    "win": {
      "target": [
        "nsis",
        "portable"
      ]
    }
  }
}

Articles suggest enabling Developer Mode on Windows to bypass the symbolic link privilege issue. However my goal is to code sign the app and I'm not sure how enabling Developer Mode would help. Running the build with administrator privileges the issue persists.
Why are macOS-specific files (libcrypto.dylib and libssl.dylib) handled during a Windows build? What steps to take for proper code signing? How can I prevent these macOS-related files from being handled during the Windows build process? Is there a better approach to resolve the symbolic link error, especially for Windows builds?

I am facing the same issue. Did you find any solution ? This PR seems to resolve the issue https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/pull/8530 but it is yet to be merged
